# requirejs on a windows phone 7

Tags: windows-7, requirejs

So I asked a question earlier about windows phone 7 with backbone and jquery and require.

I carried on investigating this and stripped it down to the bare minimum

and index page that just has

```
 <script data-main="js/main" src="js/vendor/require/requireNew.js"></script>
```

and then a main.js that just has one path to jQuery

```
require.config({
//path mappings for module names not found directly under baseUrl
paths: {
    jquery:     'vendor/jqm/jquery_1.7_min'
}

});

alert('why');

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('DOM IS READY ');
});
```

in windows 7 it will show the alert why - but not DOM is here...

it will do this on every other browser including ie7!!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using Phonegap or not, if not you should be (or an equivalent framework).

If you follow the instructions here [enter link description here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-7_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%207%20Platform%20Guide)

You will be able to build a default phonegap WP7 application when you have that take a look at the generated index.js

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // `load`, `deviceready`, `offline`, and `online`.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of `this` is the event. In order to call the `receivedEvent`
    // function, we must explicity call `app.receivedEvent(...);`
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

It's a bit more complicated on mobile devices as you first must wait for the "device ready" event before you can get a "dom ready" event